# Where should I place validation - for example: a comment can't contain some words? In a command handler or in a domain?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have the aggregate root "Post" and sub entity "Comment".

I have two questions:

1. An user cannot add a comment which contains a word "drugs". Should I validate it in a command handler or maybe in sub entity "Comment"?
2. A admin cannot change a comment status from New / Accepted / Rejected to New. Should I validate it in a command handler or maybe in sub entity "Comment"?

My command handler - here I placed validation for "drugs" but I am not sure if I am right:

```
public class CreateCommentCommand : IRequest
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; }
    public Guid PostId { get; }
    public string Author { get; }
    public string Content { get; }

    public CreateCommentCommand(Guid commentId, Guid postId, string author, string content)
    {
        CommentId = commentId;
        PostId = postId;
        Author = author;
        Content = content;
    }
}

public class CreateCommentCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateCommentCommand>
{
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateCommentCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content.Contains("drugs"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Forbidden words");
        }

        // ....

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

My sub entity "Comment" - here I placed validation for the comment status but I am not sure if I am right:

```
public class Comment : Entity
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; private set; }

    public string Author { get; private set; }

    public string Content { get; private set; }        

    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; private set; }


    public Comment(Guid commentId, string author, string content)
    {
        CommentId = commentId;
        Author = author;
        Content = content;
        CommentStatus = CommentStatus.New; 
    }


    public void ChangeStatus(CommentStatus commentStatus)
    {
        if (commentStatus == CommentStatus.New)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot change status to New");
        }

        CommentStatus = commentStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in an API or do you have a UI to work with?

Comment: this is an API .

Comment: It might be a small requirement to implement the whole design infrastructure but this sound much familiar to Event Sourcing. Each event it immutable here the event would be comment. Just putting some ideas here.

Comment: Make your comment immutable only new state can be added on top of original. you can restrict the state change as well as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> In a command handler or in a domain?

The usual answer is "in the domain".  The supporting argument is that the requirements you are describing are best understood as *business policy* implementation, and business policy is typically a domain concern, rather than a plumbing concern.

You might consider, for example, what should change if the policy changes from "reject" the comment to something like "put the comment in a moderation queue until reviewed".

Another way of thinking about this is to recognize that this is the sort of thing that you ought to be able to test without introducing a bunch of asycn/await constructs.

---

That said, please notice the "usual answer" hedge: a design isn't good because some rando on stack overflow said so, or because it follows the pattern described in The Book.  A design is good if it meets your current and future needs -- in other words, written in the way that you, and future you, and other contributors need it to be written.

The future is hard to know, so we make our best guess based on what we have learned from experience (some learned from our own mistakes, most learned from the mistakes of others -- we hope).

Comment: I think command should only mutate the object state but in this case he wants opposite. So command pattern might not be the answer. Why creating a command if it can't mutate the state of object.

Comment: I see EventSourcing as best fit but that whole big infrastructure to put in for such small requirement might not worth it. But may be something similar. Just throwing ideas.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason - so you think that I should validate a command state in a domain. What about forbidden words?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what question you are asking here.